# Код функций default

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор, оператор-присваивания, деструктор

Какой код (исходный) генерирует компилятор, если специальные функции-члены объявлены как `default`? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример на основе некоторого тестового класса или ссылку, где это показано (не нашел ничего дельного). Полагаю, это зависит от компилятора, работаю в MS Visual Studio, VC++.

Comment: Это НЕ зависит от компилятора, но зависит от конкретной функции и от параметров класса. Вы хотите, чтобы вам просто слово в слово пересказали текст из стандарта?

Comment: @AnT а можете ссылку на источник по стандарту дать и это место? Интересуют все 5 функций.

Comment: С++17. Для конструктора по умолчанию это 12.1/5. Для деструктора - 12.4/8. Для конструкторов копирования/перемещения - 12.8/15. Для операторов копирования/перемещения - 12.8/28.